# How can I make a fluid (smoke) follow a particle system?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, cache

I'm using Blender 2.82.7 for this.  I need to make a tornado, I created the particle system, I created fluid physics, but when I make the final bake the system does not behave as I wanted and it spreads.  Is there also a way to save the cache?  It takes a long time and when I close Blender I need to bake again.  I'm using Blender 2.82's new Mantaflow system.[image: Preciso que siga o movimento dessas partículas.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue is with the particle size. The default one is too big, if you reduce the size the smoke will be far better, I reduced the size to $0.01m$.

Change the particle size from: *Particle Properties -> Particle Settings -> Viewport Display -> Size*

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you! In the viewport the smoke was very soft and you can hardly see it, but I increased the density in the material and it was good. Can you send your particle system settings (just the amount of particles you used) and also those of fluid physics please?

Comment: @PCBMoreira2 Sry for the late answer. I'm adding the particle settings and physics in the below answer. Check it out....

Answer (score 0):

[[image: Particle settings for Tornado source]

[image: Particle settings for Dust source]

[image: Domain physics]

[image: Tornado source physics]**Here is the particle settings and physics for the tornado in blender 2.82**

Comment: No problem the delay, I will use them here to test, thanks.